# To pair up records in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, cross-apply

This is my sql:
when executed, it said

> 905. 00000 -  "missing keyword" on the position of "CROSS APPLY".

I'm just trying to pair up some records (in one day =`20160720`) with same TICKET_ID in the table and return their T_TIME and T_LOCATION.

```
select a.T_TIME, b.T_TIME, a.T_LOCATION, b.T_LOCATION 
FROM TABLE a 
CROSS APPLY 
(select * from TABLE b where a.TICKET_ID = b.TICKET_ID having count(TICKET_ID) > 1) b
where (a.T_DATE=20160720);
```

Is the problem caused by using `CROSS APPLY`?

Ok, here is the problem I originally want to solve ：）

The table looks like this:

```
T_TIME        |T_LOCATION   |    TICKET_ID|T_DATE
20160720091032|      ---0103|       1A268F|20160720
20160720095842|      ---0115|       63T37H|20160720
20160720133408|      ---0124|       1A268F|20160720
20160721152400|      ---0116|       598I3R|20160721
20160720125844|      ---0147|       63T37H|20160720
```

I want to pair up the records with same TICKET_ID. 2 records share one same TICKET_ID. And I want the output like:

```
20160720091032|20160720133408|0103|0124|
20160720095842|20160720125844|0115|0147|
```

The table is very large like for T_DATE=20160720 there will be 200000 records in total.

Comment: why `from TABLE...` and not `from a`, `from b`?Have you a table called `TABLE`?

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using? And I don't see the reason for a lateral join anyway. Why don't you use a regular JOIN?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - because nothing says "I have 12c and you don't" like CROSS APPLY?

Comment: @Aleksej TABLE is used for the name of my table..it is very long so I skip it~ like this:                                                                                                       select a.T_TIME, b.T_TIME, a.T_LOCATION, b.T_LOCATION 
FROM my_table_name a

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name version is 11g. I saw some webpage said cross apply performs very well...I'm not very sure if this is the correct use in my case..but the 'two selects' are from one table so I cannot use inner join, right?

Comment: Of course you can inner join a table with itself. `from the_table a join the_table b on a.ticket_id = b.ticket_id` - but the whole query doesn't really make sense. Maybe you should take a step back and describe the actual problem you are trying to solve. [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thx..I edited the question~

Comment: Do you have any column in that table that would uniquely distinguish two rows?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the T_TIME for two rows should be different~ !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it would be:

```
select a.ticket_id, a.t_time, b.t_time, a.t_location, b.t_location
from the_table a
  join the_table b on a.ticket_id = b.ticket_id and a.t_time < b.t_time
where a.t_date = 20160720;
```

The join condition `and a.t_time < b.t_time` ensure that the "other" version of a pair isn't in the result e.g. you only get (0103, 0124) but not (0124, 0103).